# Debugging program that depends on another program?

Tags: gdb

I'm working on a buffer overflow lab right now and I really need to know if something is possible.  In the lab we have two programs: bufbomb and hex2raw.  The hex2raw program converters my hex values in a text file to binary values for input in bufbomb.  In the terminal, I use this command to test my solutions:

```
cat level4.txt | ./hex2raw -n | ./bufbomb -u koppen2 -n
```

Is there ANY way to do this in gdb?  It would be extremely helpful to see where I'm actually writing to with my level4.txt hex values that I have created. E.g. If I'm actually writing over the return address or not.  I know the exact address where the return address is, so it would be easy to check, but I cannot figure out how to make gdb work the way I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is good enough for you to translate first using your program hex2raw without debugging this step, the following should allow you to pipe this interim output into bufbomb (compiled with -g, obviously) for debugging:

```
cat level4.txt | ./hex2raw > tmp.txt
gdb ./bufbomb
set args "-u koppen2 -n `cat ./tmp.txt`"
```

(the last line issued on the gdb command line). When you now `run` in gdb (after setting breakpoints etc), the required options and data should be fed to ./bufbomb. Note that there are 'accent grave' (backtick) type ticks around the cat statement, not regular ones: `, not '.

Comment: This one didn't input the string like it was supposed to.  Normally, hex2raw inputs the string into the buffer.  gdb still prompts me for a string using this method.

Answer (score 0):

```
gdb ./bufbomb
(gdb) r -u koppen2 -n <(cat level4.txt | ./hex2raw -n)
```

or even

```
gdb --args ./bufbomb -u koppen2 -n <(cat level4.txt | ./hex2raw -n)
(gdb) r
```

Comment: Neither of them work correctly.  The first one still asks me to input a string in bufbomb.  Hex2raw is supposed to automatically fill in the string.  The second one says "-u no such file or directory"

Comment: Perhaps i overestimated your shell experience, sorry. If `cat level4.txt | ./hex2raw -n | ./bufbomb -u koppen2 -n` works correctly (and if you use `bash`, maybe), then last example will too. If it does not - well, it's copy-paste from your post, so surely noone except you could know why. What is your `-u` option? What `koppen2` is? Is it a file that supposed to be in current working directory?

Comment: Ok, sorry again, argument order was indeed incorrect. Now both examples ok.